# Looping over vector updates just first item

Tags: r

I was trying to loop over a numeric vector, for instance:

```
s = c(1, 3, 7, 10, 12, 13)
```

and add leading 0 to an item if it is a numeric < 10. Else do nothing.

Desirable output: `"00", "04", "07", "10", "12", "13"`

Unfortunately I got just the first item updated:

`[1] "01" "3" "7" "10" ...`

```
for(i in 1:length(s)) {
     if (s[i] < 10) {
        s[i] <- sprintf("%02d", s[i])
     }
 }
```

Comment: You don't need a loop. You can just do `sprintf("%02d", s)`. But why did 1 turn into "00" and 3 turn into "04" in your example?

Comment: If you put one character value in a numeric vector then the whole vector is coerced to character.

Comment: @MrFlick sorry, it obviously should be: "01", "03", "07" and so on. Thanks a lot, your solution works just fine!